# Which network does truffle use for testing?

Tags: truffle, testnets, testing, truffle-test

I have a network 'foo' that is configured inside `truffle.js`. Running my tests works just fine

```
truffle test --network foo ./test/*.js
```

then I realized I forgot to start 'foo'.
To confirm this running the console fails.

```
truffle console --network foo
```

How is it that my tests can pass even saying `Using network 'foo'` while the network is not running?

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean `forgot to start 'foo'`? How exactly are you "starting foo"?

Comment: I forgot starting geth.

Comment: In your truffle configuration file, what are your `host` and `port` settings for the `foo` network?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` and `8545` but the problem is that `truffle test` works - not that `truffle console` doesn't.

Comment: When I start `geth` connecting the with `truffle console` works just as expected.

Comment: What's the console output of Truffle when running the tests?
That "should" tell you how and what's going on. IE: is Truffle spinning up it's own testrpc to complete the test cases

Answer (score 3):

Turns out `truffle test` automatically starts a ganache instance if there is no test network. See the [github issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1993). The `truffle test --network foo` seems to fall back to the default instance if the network `foo` is down.